# Link external library GCC OS X

Tags: gcc, hyperlink, gmp

I have installed `GCC` 4.7.2 and `GMP` 5.1.0 and I've written this simple code in `main.cpp` locate at `~/Desktop`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gmp.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    mpz_t a;

    mpz_init(a);

    mpz_set_ui(a, 42);

    cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;
}
```

I compile it with:

```
$ g++ main.cpp -o exe
```

but I get this error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___gmpz_init", referenced from:
      _main in ccC0FXun.o
  "___gmpz_set_ui", referenced from:
      _main in ccC0FXun.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I think it's because it doesn't find the `GMP` library, am I right?

So how can I link an external library such as `GMP` in `GCC`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program works fine for me here using:

```
g++ main.cpp -o exe -lgmp
```

Check the [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options) for a description of the `-l` flag.

Comment: Ok it works with the -lgmp flag. But for example why don't I have to write -liostream?

Comment: Because `iostream` isn't a library, it's a header file, and the corresponding library (often `libstdc++`) is implicitly included in the link when using `g++`.

Comment: And for example if I also have to use an `acme.a`library which has already been installed I have to write: `$ g++ main.cpp -o exe -lgmp -lacme`, right?

Comment: Maybe, that depends on where it is and how you want to use it.  The documentation linked above tells you everything you need to know.